# code not running properly 

Tags: android

Some time gets "Launch Cancelled" error.  Gets stuck at 'Open Time Sheet ' Button `btn01`.
Any help is appreciated.

TimeSheet.java

```
package com.example.TimeSheet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TimeSheet extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuExample.class));

    }
}
```

MenuExample.java

```
package com.example.TimeSheet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MenuExample extends Activity
{    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.menu);        
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);        
        btn.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.setQwertyMode(true);
        MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Fill Time Sheet");
        {
            mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
            mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
        }
        MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Check Time Sheet");
        {
            mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('b');
            mnu2.setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);            
        }
        MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Exit Time Sheet");
        {
            mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('c');
            mnu3.setIcon(R.drawable.icon3);
        }

    }

    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
    {        
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 1", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 2", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 3", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        }
        return false;


    }  


    // Using Context Menu
    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        CreateMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {    
         return MenuChoice(item);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, 
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
         CreateMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {    
         return MenuChoice(item);    
    } 
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


</LinearLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text = "Open Time Sheet"/>            

</LinearLayout>
```

..................................
[2010-09-27 00:51:57 - TimeSheet] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-27 00:51:57 - TimeSheet] Uploading TimeSheet.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-27 00:52:08 - TimeSheet] Failed to upload TimeSheet.apk on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-27 00:52:08 - TimeSheet] java.io.IOException: Unable to upload file: null
[2010-09-27 00:52:08 - TimeSheet] Launch canceled!

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience because of false editing.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text = "Open Time Sheet"/>            
 
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the exact error you are getting, including stack trace?  use adb logcat to get the stack trace.

Comment: i cnt put d whole stack trace here....

Comment: I have edited question with stack trace.Please help me out. I have gone through other questions from site to get help, but unfortunately, solutions mentioned there are not useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB connection timeout...

Set to something bigger, like 10000 (ms).

I was having the same problem and this solved it.